# CV Template Reverse Engineering

Tags: cv

I stumpled upon this CV template and would like to reverse engineer it: https://jhalderm.com/home/halderman-cv.pdf

Two main questions:

- Which font (and sizes) are being used? (The list of embedded fonts suggests `kpfonts.sty`)
- How can I generate the bibtex output in terms of:

  - 1st line: title (linked with a \href)
  - 2nd line: authors, where my own name is underlined

Comment: Did you try asking the author if he would be willing to share the source document with you?

Comment: Not much, but with `mutool extract halderman-cv.pdf` command (assuming you have `mupdf` and `mutools` installed) you can extract all fonts embedded in *.pfa format.